# How to pass a parameter to a regular expression inside of a Python user-defined function?

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics

Say I have a string of characters like:

'TTATGACGTTATTCTACTTTGATTGTGCGAGACAATGCTACCTTACCGGTCGGAACTCGATCGGTTGAACTCTATCACGCCTGGTCTTCGAAGTTAGCA'

And I would like to use a regular expression like re.findall to locate any instances of 3 entries (e.g. TTA or GTT for instance).

How can I pass the sub-string to a user-defined function such that this is possible?

What I tried was something like this:

```
def finder(sequence, codons):
    Y = re.findall(r'codons',sequence)
    return Y
```

However, when I attempt to call this function on my string that I gave above using some input for codons like 'TTA', all I get as a return is an empty list...

I think the list is empty because within the regular expression in my function, "codons" is within the quotation marks next to the r. Is there a way to pass something to a regular expression in a manner that circumvents this?

Comment: Remove the quotes from around `codons`. It's the name of a variable just like `sequence`

Comment: Why are you using regex for this at all?

Comment: Provide a sample of the input you use for `sequence` please.

Comment: Using `re.findall()`, you'll get a list like `['TTA', 'TTA', ...]`, which doesn't seem all that useful. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to match the string `"codons"`, rather than the variable parameter. Try this:

```
def finder(sequence, codons):
   return re.findall(codons, sequence)
```

Answer (score 2):

A polished answer of your question (using python 3+):

```
# codon_search.py
import re

def finder(codon, fullseq):
    matched = re.findall(codon, fullseq)
    print (matched) 

sequence = "TTATGACGTTATTCTACTTTGATTGTGCGAGACAATGCTACCTTACCGGTCGGAAC"
search_str = "TTA"

#call function
finder(search_str, sequence)
```

---

Output: 3 matches will be found in the above sequence

```
['TTA', 'TTA', 'TTA']
```